# Single hotkey for multiple options

Tags: shortcut

From time to time, after pressing a hotkey button corresponding to an action (eg. `V` for "Set handle type" in edit Bezier curve mode), I get to choose from multiple options, but they all have the same hotkey assigned to them:

[image: screenshot]

How do I tell Blender which option to choose with just the keyboard? Is there a way to tell "always choose this one (eg. Toggle) until I choose something else (without going to preferences and changing the binding).

Answer (score 3):

Open **User preferences** → **Keymap**. You can find key-building by key name or navigate to **3D-view** → **Curve** → **Curve Global**.

Expand **Set Handle Type** and select type that you want:

[image]

If you want to add a new hot-key, copy-paste the name of the operator from the text field in the new keymap item: `curve.handle_type_set`

Comment: Thanks! That doesn't entirely work, as I cannot set `V V` as it's already chosen by "Vector": do you know if there's a way to change these second-order keybinds?

Ideally, I would like the behavior to be like this: `V` opens the popup and another `V` repeats the previous operation, and there are other letters (or click) to choose others.

Answer (score 1):

I just learned that the underline in the text of the hotkey defines the second hotkey to choose the option, so, e.g. `V V` corresponds to **V**ector, `V T` to **T**oogle, etc.

I still don't know how to change it, though.

Comment: Underlined letters in menus are *"access keys"*, a Windows convention. While I wouldn't correct someone for calling them *"shortcuts"*, it's important to note it's in the very least a different category of shortcuts than those *globally* accessible.